# XSLT: running a stylesheet w/o having <xi:include> resolve themelves

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to add a processing instruction after each `<xi:include>` element.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xi:include">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="hard-pagebreak"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that as soon as I apply this to my contents.xml file (which is a listing of a whole bunch of `<xi:include>`, the tags gets resolved and the file is essentially flattened (i.e. the `<xi:include>` are replaced with what they represent.  This seems to happen whenever I run any stylesheet on contents.xml

Is there a way to run a stylesheet without having the `<xi:include>` become resolved?  Maybe turning off a xslt parser or something for the duration of that stylesheet???

Comment: Specific XSLT processor configuration/feature/behavior. Retagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use an XML parser that doesn't understand `xi:include` or set the right switch for prevent the `xi:include` processing by the parser.

If these are not possible, then you must include your processing in the same transformation that generates the `xi:include` elements.

Comment: Ok I ran a parser that doesn't touch the `<xi:include>`, but the transformation i just did, changed `<xi:include href='blah'/>` to `<xi:include href='blah'>`</xi:include>`.  it may seem aesthetic, but I'd like to have as little effect on the xml as possible.

Comment: Then in your template matching `xi:include` replace `<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>` with `<xi:include href="{@href}"/>`

Comment: For Saxon, the command line switch -xi controls whether or not XInclude elements are expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use an XSLT processor that doesn't understand the `<xi:include>` tags. What are you using to run the XSLT at the moment?

I'm pretty sure that the Microsoft XSLT processor would not process these:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2fb55371-c94e-4373-b0e9-db4816552e41&displaylang=en